# Fullmetal Alchemist "let's go" translation

Tags: anime

In Fullmetal Alchemist season 1 episode 15 ("The Ishbal Massacre") at the 22:00 minute mark Person A says to Person B something that sounds to me like:

> ないぎましょう

It is translated as "let's go" in the subtitles.
Since I could not find a japanese transcription of said episode I want to know:

1.) Did I understand correctly?
2.) If not, what did she say? If yes, is this somehow related to 行きましょう or 行くin general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The woman says 参｛まい｝りましょう, which is a humble way of saying "Let us go". It is not something that you say to your superiors, but should rather be used by superiors towards those of lower rank, or possibly between people of the same rank depending on the friendliness level.

The reason you should not use it to superiors, assuming they are also part of the "going" action, is because it is a way of lowering the status of the subject of the action (humble language). If the subject of the action includes your superior, then you are lowering his status as well. However, you can use it to superiors if you are the only subject, e.g.

コーヒーを持って参りましょうか？ Should I get you a coffee?

For more information, check one of the many answers concerning Humble language 謙譲語｛けんじょうご｝

Comment: `It is not something that you say to your superiors`-- 目上の人に「Let us go」と丁寧に言うには、「参りましょう」が駄目なら、何と言うのがよいでしょう？

Comment: そういう場合には目上の人と自分の動作をまとめて表すのではなく、例えば「~長、そろそろお出かけになりますか」のように目上の人を主語として話すのが好ましいだと思います。